# Como realizar uma operação sem mostrar o resultado em C?

Tags: c, variáveis

Preciso de um modo que o programa realize uma conta entre variáveis `x` e `y` e guarde o resultado em uma variável `z`, como faço isso em C?

Comment: Tem que tentar algo e postar o código detalhando onde está a dificuldade.

Comment: Qual é a conta que deve realizar?

Comment: adição entre a variável x e a variável y, resultando na variável z

Comment: Escreves uma função que realize a conta e devolva o resultado: `z = conta(x, y);`

Comment: @Strule A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Seria isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    printf("Entre com 2 números: ");
    scanf("%i %i", &x, &y);
    int z = x + y;
    printf("\n%i", z);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OeKlxF). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jpsfwgtx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Variable.c).

Esta linha `printf("%i",z, y+x==z);` está a maior confusão. Isto está somando as duas variáveis e comparando com `z`, não está atribuindo à variável conforme pedido. E está mandando 2 argumentos para a formatação do `printf()`.

Também as variáveis não foram inicializadas e eventualmente pode trazer problemas. Ainda a falta de organização dificulta a leitura do código. Organizando fica mais fácil entender o que está acontecendo.